# Unable to update local file via POST method using Fetch in JavaScript application

Tags: javascript, json, post, fetch

I was able to successfully read the JSON file using the Fetch method and providing a relative path to the resource; however, when I try to update JSON file using the same local path I am getting `405 Error (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed))`.

Is there some additional configuration that is required for fetch to be able to accept post methods, or do I need to start a json server?

```
// getting data
fetch('./contacts.json')
    .then(res => {
        return res.json();
    })
.then(data => {
    data.forEach(post => {
        userContacts.set(post.id, new Contact(
            post.fName,
            post.lName,
            post.phone,
            post.address
        ))
    })
});
 
// using POST method
fetch('./contacts.json', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type" : 'application/json',
    },
    body : JSON.stringify(newContactJ)
}).then(res => {
        // guard clause
        if (!res.ok){
        console.log('problem, try again');
        return
        } 
        return res.json()
})
```

Comment: Where is this happening? Front end or back end? The short answer is no, you can't use POST to update local JSON like that. You need to write the file - and depending on your environment you need to take different approaches.

Comment: Where do you have any server-side code to handle this POST request?  If you're expecting `fetch` to be an API for writing files to your file system then I'm afraid your expectation is simply incorrect.

Comment: @Andy This is happening on the Front End. This is a project I am working on and launching it via Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @David there is currently no server-side implementation. Thank you for clarification.